# PHP - Grab PDF with URL that does not have the .pdf extension

Tags: php, pdf, filepicker.io

I'm using Filepicker.io to upload PDFs to my application. I have all those URLs and now I am trying to merge some of those PDFs using the PDF Tool Kit PHP library. It was not working for me so I ran some tests using the "file_exists" on PHP and it kept returning false.

I think this has to do with the fact that the URL does not have a ".pdf" extension at the end. This is what they look like: "https://www.filepicker.io/api/file/LCvbgpqEQLGwt8bfnqc1"

Does anyone know how I can pull the PDF using PHP in order to merge those files using the PDF Toolkit Library?

Thanks!

Alain F.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`file_exists`](http://php.net/file_exists) doesn't work with URLs, only with local files. Instead download the file to the temp dir using the [`copy`](http://php.net/copy) command.

If the file can't be downloaded, the copy command will return `false`.

```
$exists = copy('https://www.filepicker.io/api/file/LCvbgpqEQLGwt8bfnqc1', '/tmp/example.pdf');
if (!$exists) throw new Exception("PDF could not be downloaded");
```

Use the downloaded file in the PDF Tool Kit.

Comment: Eexplain a little more on what your code does, theres no educational values in just posting a snippet

Comment: @DarylGill There you go :)

Answer (score 0):

*EDIT:* This does not solve this particular problem but does address the theory that it didn't work because "the URL does not have a ".pdf" extension at the end."

You can add things to the end of the filepicker URL with a trailing +

The following urls are equivalent:

```
https://www.filepicker.io/api/file/LCvbgpqEQLGwt8bfnqc1
https://www.filepicker.io/api/file/LCvbgpqEQLGwt8bfnqc1+name.pdf
```